# Is this MySQL statement injection secure?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

It's been AGES since I did any MySQL and I've been learning a little about PDO. I just wondered whether this was the correct way to do things?

Thanks in advance!

```
$sql = 'SELECT `something`,`somethingelse` FROM here WHERE id = \'' . $_REQUEST["id"] . '\'';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Well if `$_REQUEST["id"]` contains e.g.`1' OR '1'='1`, then your query would be `SELECT something,somethingelse FROM here WHERE id = '1' OR '1'='1'`, so not it is not secure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, never add variables directly into the query string. Here is the secure way to do it. This looks like a PDO query, so here is how to substitute values into a pdo query

```
$sql = 'SELECT `something`, `somethingelse` FROM here WHERE id = ?';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_REQUEST["id"] ));
```

or you can shorten it a little further thus saving time by doing:

```
$stmt->execute([$_REQUEST['id']])
```

You can read a little more on how to run the queries here https://yomotherboard.com/sql-prepared-statements-using-php-pdo-queres/